# Persistent memoization in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, persistence, memoization, file-locking

I have an expensive function that takes and returns a small amount of data (a few integers and floats).  I have already [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) this function, but I would like to make the memo persistent.  There are already a couple of threads relating to this, but I'm unsure about potential issues with some of the suggested approaches, and I have some fairly specific requirements:

- I will definitely use the function from multiple threads and processes simultaneously (both using `multiprocessing` and from separate python scripts)
- I will not need read or write access to the memo from outside this python function
- I am not that concerned about the memo being corrupted on rare occasions (like pulling the plug or accidentally writing to the file without locking it) as it isn't *that* expensive to rebuild (typically 10-20 minutes) but I would prefer if it would not be corrupted because of exceptions, or manually terminating a python process (I don't know how realistic that is)
- I would strongly prefer solutions that don't require large external libraries as I have a severely limited amount of hard disk space on one machine I will be running the code on
- I have a weak preference for cross-platform code, but I will likely only use this on Linux

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486490/python-shelve-module-question) discusses the `shelve` module, which is apparently not process-safe.  Two of the answers suggest using `fcntl.flock` to lock the shelve file.  Some of the responses in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python), however, seem to suggest that this is fraught with problems - but I'm not exactly sure what they are.  It sounds as though this is limited to Unix (though apparently Windows has an equivalent called `msvcrt.locking`), and the lock is only 'advisory' - i.e., it won't stop me from accidentally writing to the file without checking it is locked.  Are there any other potential problems?  Would writing to a copy of the file, and replacing the master copy as a final step, reduce the risk of corruption?

It doesn't look as though the [dbm module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/dbm.html) will do any better than shelve.  I've had a quick look at [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html), but it seems a bit overkill for this purpose.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235594/comparing-persistent-storage-solutions-in-python) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428103/is-there-an-established-memoize-on-disk-decorator-for-python) mention several 3rd party libraries, including [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/index.html), but there are a lot of choices, and they all seem overly large and complicated for this task.

Does anyone have any advice?

**UPDATE**: kindall mentioned IncPy below, which does look very interesting.  Unfortunately, I wouldn't want to move back to Python 2.6 (I'm actually using 3.2), and it looks like it is a bit awkward to use with C libraries (I make heavy use of numpy and scipy, among others).

kindall's other idea is instructive, but I think adapting this to multiple processes would be a little difficult - I suppose it would be easiest to replace the queue with file locking or a database.

Looking at ZODB again, it does look perfect for the task, but I really do want to avoid using any additional libraries.  I'm still not entirely sure what all the issues with simply using `flock` are - I imagine one big problem is if a process is terminated while writing to the file, or before releasing the lock?

So, I've taken synthesizerpatel's advice and gone with sqlite3.  If anyone's interested, I decided to make a drop-in replacement for `dict` that stores its entries as pickles in a database (I don't bother to keep any in memory as database access and pickling is fast enough compared to everything else I'm doing).  I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this (and I've no idea whether I might still have concurrency issues), but here is the code:

```
from collections import MutableMapping
import sqlite3
import pickle


class PersistentDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, dbpath, iterable=None, **kwargs):
        self.dbpath = dbpath
        with self.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'create table if not exists memo '
                '(key blob primary key not null, value blob not null)'
            )
        if iterable is not None:
            self.update(iterable)
        self.update(kwargs)

    def encode(self, obj):
        return pickle.dumps(obj)

    def decode(self, blob):
        return pickle.loads(blob)

    def get_connection(self):
        return sqlite3.connect(self.dbpath)

    def  __getitem__(self, key):
        key = self.encode(key)
        with self.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'select value from memo where key=?',
                (key,)
            )
            value = cursor.fetchone()
        if value is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self.decode(value[0])

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = self.encode(key)
        value = self.encode(value)
        with self.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'insert or replace into memo values (?, ?)',
                (key, value)
            )

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        key = self.encode(key)
        with self.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'select count(*) from memo where key=?',
                (key,)
            )
            if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
                raise KeyError(key)
            cursor.execute(
                'delete from memo where key=?',
                (key,)
            )

    def __iter__(self):
        with self.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'select key from memo'
            )
            records = cursor.fetchall()
        for r in records:
            yield self.decode(r[0])

    def __len__(self):
        with self.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'select count(*) from memo'
            )
            return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: If you can deal with Python 2.6.3 and aren't on Windows, you might want to check out [IncPy](http://www.stanford.edu/~pgbovine/incpy.html) which will automatically and persistently memoize your *whole program* everywhere it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sqlite3 out of the box provides [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). File locking is prone to race-conditions and concurrency problems that you won't have using sqlite3.

Basically, yeah, sqlite3 is more than what you need, but it's not a huge burden. It can run on mobile phones, so it's not like you're committing to running some beastly software. It's going to save you time reinventing wheels and debugging locking issues.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want to continue to memoize the results of the function in RAM, probably in a dictionary, but use the persistence to reduce the "warmup" time of the application. In this case you're not going to be randomly accessing items *directly in the backing store* so a database might indeed be overkill (though as **synthesizerpatel** notes, maybe not as much as you think).

Still, if you want to roll your own, a viable strategy might be to simply load the dictionary from a file at the beginning of your run before starting any threads. When a result isn't in the dictionary, then you need to write it to the file after adding it to the dictionary. You can do this by adding it to a queue and using a single worker thread that flushes items from the queue to disk (just appending them to a single file would be fine). You might occasionally add the same result more than once, but this is not fatal since it'll be the same result each time, so reading it back in twice or more will do no real harm. Python's threading model will keep you out of most kinds of concurrency trouble (e.g., appending to a list is atomic).

Here is some (untested, generic, incomplete) code showing what I'm talking about:

```
import cPickle as pickle

import time, os.path

cache = {}
queue = []

# run at script start to warm up cache
def preload_cache(filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            while True:
                try:
                    key, value = pickle.load(f), pickle.load(f)
                except EOFError:
                    break
                cache[key] = value

# your memoized function
def time_consuming_function(a, b, c, d):
    key = (a, b, c, d)
    if key in cache:
        return cache[key]
    else:
        # generate the result here
        # ...
        # add to cache, checking to see if it's already there again to avoid writing
        # it twice (in case another thread also added it) (this is not fatal, though)
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = result
            queue.append((key, result))
        return result

# run on worker thread to write new items out
def write_cache(filename):
    with open(filename, "ab") as f:
        while True:
            while queue:
                key, value = queue.pop()  # item order not important
                # but must write key and value in single call to ensure
                # both get written (otherwise, interrupting script might
                # leave only one written, corrupting the file)
                f.write(pickle.dumps(key, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) +
                        pickle.dumps(value, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
            f.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
```

If I had time, I'd turn this into a decorator... and put the persistence into a `dict` subclass... the use of global variables is also sub-optimal. :-) If you use this approach with `multiprocessing` you'd probably want to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` rather than a list; you can then use `queue.get()` as a blocking wait for a new result in the worker process that writes to the file. I've not used `multiprocessing`, though, so take this bit of advice with a grain of salt.